# UWP/.NET Core: What type of project for a service app providing support for UWP and Xamarin apps

Tags: .net, xamarin, asp.net-core, uwp, .net-core

So I have a solution for retail which consists of:

- Main App used by the operator on a POS Machine - written in UWP (side loaded)
- Self-Service app used by the customer on an Android Tablet - written using Xamarin

Now I have a need to a third app, which doesn't have to have an UI, only REST endpoints listening for calls from above two apps, and responsing to them (WebSockets would be good) and doing some processing and allowing communication.
Sample use cases would be:

- Send to the printer some data to print
- Send to the MainApp some request to be displayed to the operator
- Send to the TableApp some request as above.

In the full .NET Framework I would create a ASP.NET WebAPI, or a WindowsService, but I want it to be compatible with the latest standards as possible. So using .NET Core, and perfectly if I could run it e.g. on a Rasperry Pi, or on the same machine were the MainApp is running.

What type of project should I use?

I was thinking about following options:

- UWP AppService [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)
- ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Comment: I am not sure how it is related to Xamarin. If I got what you are trying to do is to host WebAPI/web service. I wouldn't use Xamarin at all to host those. As you said - use ASP.NET if it is compatible with Raspberry Pi OSes. What I am missing?

Comment: yes an xamarin app will be just a client for the service, so it might be not related, just wanted to describe the full picture.

Comment: Then I don't get the question.